# Android Studio 3.5 indexing issues with instant libs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-instant-apps

Error Log:

```
com.intellij.util.IncorrectOperationException: Incorrect package name: null
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementFactoryImpl.createPackageStatement(PsiElementFactoryImpl.java:449)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.setPackageName(PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.java:125)
    at com.android.tools.idea.databinding.psiclass.LightBrClass.<init>(LightBrClass.kt:111)
    at com.android.tools.idea.databinding.psiclass.DataBindingClassFactory.getOrCreateBrClassFor(DataBindingClassFactory.java:63)
    at com.android.tools.idea.databinding.finders.BrClassFinder$1.compute(BrClassFinder.kt:42)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.lambda$getValueWithLock$0(CachedValueBase.java:236)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$1.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:116)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:237)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.android.tools.idea.databinding.finders.BrClassFinder.findClass(BrClassFinder.kt:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.databinding.finders.BrClassFinder.findClasses(BrClassFinder.kt:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.databinding.finders.BrClassFinder.getClasses(BrClassFinder.kt:55)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.JavaPsiFacadeImpl.getClasses(JavaPsiFacadeImpl.java:293)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.PsiPackageImpl.getClasses(PsiPackageImpl.java:158)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.PsiPackageImpl.processDeclarations(PsiPackageImpl.java:317)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.processPackageDeclarations(PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.java:484)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.processCurrentPackage(PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.java:398)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.processDeclarationsNoGuess(PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.java:334)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.access$200(PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.java:40)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileBaseImpl$MyCacheBuilder.compute(PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.java:595)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.lambda$getValueWithLock$0(CachedValueBase.java:236)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$1.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:116)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:237)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.processDeclarations(PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.java:314)
    at com.intellij.psi.scope.util.PsiScopesUtil.treeWalkUp(PsiScopesUtil.java:69)
    at com.intellij.psi.scope.util.PsiScopesUtil.treeWalkUp(PsiScopesUtil.java:51)
    at com.intellij.psi.scope.util.PsiScopesUtil.resolveAndWalk(PsiScopesUtil.java:218)
    at com.intellij.psi.scope.util.PsiScopesUtil.resolveAndWalk(PsiScopesUtil.java:149)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:501)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:534)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.access$100(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:44)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl$OurGenericsResolver.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:383)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl$OurGenericsResolver.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:375)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.lambda$resolveWithCaching$1(ResolveCache.java:203)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$1.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:116)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolveWithCaching(ResolveCache.java:202)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiImplUtil.multiResolveImpl(PsiImplUtil.java:797)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiImplUtil.multiResolveImpl(PsiImplUtil.java:788)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.multiResolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:434)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.advancedResolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:427)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:359)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ClassResolverProcessor.<init>(ClassResolverProcessor.java:54)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:500)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:534)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.access$100(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:44)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl$OurGenericsResolver.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:383)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl$OurGenericsResolver.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:375)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.lambda$resolveWithCaching$1(ResolveCache.java:203)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$1.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:116)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolveWithCaching(ResolveCache.java:202)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiImplUtil.multiResolveImpl(PsiImplUtil.java:797)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiImplUtil.multiResolveImpl(PsiImplUtil.java:788)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.multiResolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:434)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.advancedResolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:427)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:359)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ClassResolverProcessor.<init>(ClassResolverProcessor.java:54)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:500)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:534)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.access$100(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:44)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl$OurGenericsResolver.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:383)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl$OurGenericsResolver.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:375)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.lambda$resolveWithCaching$1(ResolveCache.java:203)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$1.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:116)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolveWithCaching(ResolveCache.java:202)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiImplUtil.multiResolveImpl(PsiImplUtil.java:797)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.getCanonicalText(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:297)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.getCanonicalText(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:281)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiAnnotationImpl.getQualifiedName(PsiAnnotationImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.findOwnAnnotations(AnnotationUtil.java:107)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.findAllAnnotations(AnnotationUtil.java:84)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtil.java:66)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtil.java:50)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtil.java:43)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiImplUtil.isDeprecatedByAnnotation(PsiImplUtil.java:449)
    at com.intellij.psi.stub.JavaStubImplUtil.isMemberDeprecated(JavaStubImplUtil.java:54)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassImpl.isDeprecated(PsiClassImpl.java:413)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.BasePsiMemberNode.isDeprecated(BasePsiMemberNode.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.AbstractPsiBasedNode.lambda$doUpdate$1(AbstractPsiBasedNode.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:941)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.AbstractPsiBasedNode.doUpdate(AbstractPsiBasedNode.java:138)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.AbstractPsiBasedNode.lambda$update$0(AbstractPsiBasedNode.java:134)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.lambda$toComputable$2(AstLoadingFilter.java:169)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.disallowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:127)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.disallowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:116)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.disallowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.AbstractPsiBasedNode.update(AbstractPsiBasedNode.java:134)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.PresentableNodeDescriptor.getUpdatedPresentation(PresentableNodeDescriptor.java:89)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.PresentableNodeDescriptor.update(PresentableNodeDescriptor.java:41)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeBuilder.updateNodeDescriptor(AbstractTreeBuilder.java:496)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$20.perform(AbstractTreeUi.java:923)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.TreeRunnable.run(TreeRunnable.java:23)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1821)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.update(AbstractTreeUi.java:919)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.update(AbstractTreeUi.java:871)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.processExistingNode(AbstractTreeUi.java:2965)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.lambda$null$5(AbstractTreeUi.java:1684)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1800)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$5100(AbstractTreeUi.java:50)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$30.perform(AbstractTreeUi.java:1766)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.TreeRunnable.run(TreeRunnable.java:23)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.executeYieldingRequest(AbstractTreeUi.java:2056)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$5700(AbstractTreeUi.java:50)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$33$1.perform(AbstractTreeUi.java:1968)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.TreeRunnable.run(TreeRunnable.java:23)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeBuilder.runOnYieldingDone(AbstractTreeBuilder.java:347)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.runOnYieldingDone(AbstractTreeUi.java:2151)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$33.perform(AbstractTreeUi.java:1963)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.TreeRunnable.run(TreeRunnable.java:23)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeBuilder.lambda$yield$1(AbstractTreeBuilder.java:365)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:435)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:403)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:757)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:706)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:375)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

We are having some problem with Studio indexing after migrating to Android Studio 3.5. Indexing/Navigation/AutoComplete does not work at all even though it builds fine.

We have 2 instant app modules one with plugin `'com.android.feature'` and other with `'com.android.instantapp'`. Removing these 2 out from `setings.gradle` seems to make Studio happy.

Unloading these modules also fixes this problem.

Can anybody point out the problem(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `com.android.instantapp` as well as `com.android.feature` plugins are deprecated.
Use `com.android.application` in combination with `com.android.dynamic-feature` instead.

See this post for more info: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/04/google-play-instant-feature-plugin.html